# Inductive and projective tensor product

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, tensor-products

Does anyone know if there is a characterization of the spaces on which the inductive tensor product and the projective tensor product are the same ? This is the same as asking every separately continuous bilinear form to be continuous. It is the case for the tensor product of Fréchet spaces for example.

Comment: This question might be of some relevance: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/123879/inductive-tensor-product-and-smooth-functions/123885#123885

Comment: Isn't this Grothendiek definition of nuclearity?